# "Variable might not have been initialized" Error not given at compile time

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

While developing an API using SpringBoot, I had to make a `QueryBuilder`
in order to build a query which can fetch results from Database using JDBC.

My initial structure of `Query` looked Like

```
public static class Query {
    private String table;
    private QueryType queryType;
    private List<String> column;
    private List<Fields> where;
    private List<String> groupBy;
    private String orderBy;
    private Map<String,Object> extraFields;
}
```

To set the values in given fields I used public functions like :

```
public Query addTable(final String tableName){
        this.table = tableName;
        return this;
    }

public Query addExtraField( String key, Object value){
        if(null==this.extraFields)
            extraFields = new HashMap<>();
        this.extraFields.put(key,value);
        return this;
    }
```

And to finally build the query a function called `toQuery()` was used which appended different clauses of a query into one string.

`toQuery()` Function looked like folowing:

```
 private static String toQuery(Query query){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(query.queryType.name());
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

And a `query` was then built by using :

```
QueryBuilder.Query().addTable(sometable).addQueryType(sometype).addExtraFields(somefieldsmap).toQuery();
```

However, some queries required `ExtraFields` while some did not. So, in `toQuery()` function I used following code :

```
if(query.extraFields()==null || query.extraFields.size()<2){
 // do Something
}
```

Now, my question is that why didn't it throw an error at the compile time saying that I could not use `.size()` condition because it was possible that the `extraFields Map` was not intialized depending upon the fact that `addExtraFields()` was used or not. It kept throwing `NullPointerException` on the runtime when the condition occured but did not throw an error on Compile time like it does in following simple example :

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.io.*;
 class Ideone{
     public static void main (String[] args) {
       HashMap<String, String> map;
       boolean temp = false;
       if(temp){map = new HashMap<>();}
       System.out.println(map.size());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Because "not initialized" is something very different than "null value". The field has the value `null` by default.

Comment: Try to remove the parentheses here `if(query.extraFields()==null`. It should be `if(query.extraFields==null`

Answer (score 1):

The fields of a class do not need to be explicitly initialized before use.  They are implicitly initialized to the default value for the field's type:

- `false` for the type `boolean`
- zero for a primitive numeric type
- `null` for a reference type.

That is why `query.extraFields` is `null` in some circumstances.

The rules are different for local variables, which is why your last example is a compilation error.  (According to the JLS *definite assignment* rules, there is a path to the `println` call in which `map` may not have been assigned a value.  Since `map` is a local variable, this is a compilation error.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as to why the last code block throws compilation error, we need to refer to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html):

> For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be
>   definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.

Because the variable `map` is declared without initialization.  The initialization happens inside an if-block, so the compiler cannot *definitely* know if it was initialized or not, hence the compilation error. If you were to change `boolean temp` to final and assign it `true` value, the compiler error will disappear because now the variable `temp` is final, so the compiler can determine that the if block must have been executed and the `map` variable initialized *definitely*.